# Ubuntu on Dell Optiplex 755/760 - shall I expect any issues with graphics/audio/stability?

Tags: drivers, dell

I'm looking for a computer for my friend who wants to have Ubuntu on a cheap pc. I found some Dells Optiplex 755/760 that fit the price but I wonder if I should expect any issues with graphics (Intel GMA 3100/4500), onboard audio, chipset etc or is Ubuntu working right after the installation?

I do not yet have this computer so using a LiveCD will not work ;-)

And aside question: will the UbuntuGNOME/Xubuntu run smooth on such hardware? My friend especially wants to watch Youtube movies and browse simple websites.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience. Dells themselves do not last long, and are built with profit rather than quality in mind. But as this is an Ubuntu forum I should move on...

Obviously, the best thing for you would be someone who has that computer to tell you it is working fine. In the absence of that the best thing to do is google the part number, and the Ubuntu version you plan to install. If there is nothing on forums about that part, or the only things are fixed or have an easy solution then it should be fine. The big thing to watch out for is the wireless driver if you are going onto 13.10. A lot of people have been having wireless issues with 13.10. For stability, especially for a friend who does not like having to deal with issues when things update, I personally would recommend putting on 12.04LTS.